# What is a simple way to Cache a List (or other Collection) in Java

Tags: java, caching, collections

I have a Collection in the form of a List pulled out of the database that will never change once it is pulled; every user in the system will see the same thing. I have been trying to figure out the simplest way to cache it. I know I can use CacheBuilder from Guava, but it seems like overkill to create a cached map with 1 item in it that never changes.

Comment: hmm just keep that list somewhere in memory in one of your objects?

Comment: Guava's `Suppliers.memoize()` is preferred for single item caches.

Comment: @BenManes  That is exactly what I was looking for, and worked perfectly.

Comment: Since this was written, Ben Manes has written the Caffeine Caching system. Wonder if the guava example is still the best, or using Caffeine with a constant string as the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From @BenManes above, I used Suppliers.memoize:

```
private Supplier<Collection<Person>> cache = Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(
        new Supplier<Collection<Employee>>() {
            public Collection<Employee> get() {
                return getAllEmployees();
            }
        }, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

public Collection<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
    return cache.get();
}
```

Comment: Suppliers.memoizeWithExpiration(() -> CODE).get()